# como posso inserir o valor de um input type = "file" em outro tipo de entrada oculto

Tags: javascript, html

como posso inserir o valor de um input type = "file" em outro tipo de entrada oculto. Por favor, ajudem eu sei que é uma pergunta bebê de qualquer maneira por favor ajude caras.Eu quero-o feito em javascript ou jQuery ou php

Comment: Formulários com entradas `file` e tipo `multipart/form-data` enviam todos os dados (parâmetros e conteúdo do arquivo) não "URL Encoded" mas no corpo (*body*) da requisição ([fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8660740/520779)). Isso é feito automaticamente pro conteúdo do arquivo. Se você quer ter maior controle sobre o processo (por exemplo pegando o conteúdo do arquivo, codificando-o de alguma maneira e usando-o como valor do campo escondido) a única forma que sei é através das [APIs do HTML5 para manipulação de arquivo](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer? talvez dê para usar outra lógica que resolva o seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o conteúdo de um arquivo usando um [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), transformar ele em uma string base64 e coloca-lo no hidden input

```
var fileUpload  = document.getElementById('fileUpload'),
    hiddenField = document.getElementById('hiddenField');

function fileChanged() {
    function onLoad(e) {
        // Adicionando o arquivo em base64 ao hidden field:
        hiddenField.innerHTML = e.target.result;
    }

    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = onLoad;
        // Isso vai transformar o arquivo em uma string base64:
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

document.getElementById('#fileUpload')
    .addEventListener('change', fileChanged, false);
```